# Hapi.js Bell/Auth-Cookie Redirect Loop

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I am trying to setup google auth for a Hapi.js project and I cannot see why I am getting a redirect loop back to my login route after logging in.

This is only occurring if the user wasn't already logged into their google account or hasn't yet granted permission for the app to access their info.

This is the auth registration code

```
server.auth.strategy('session', 'cookie', true, {
   password: 'private_key',
   redirectTo: '/login/google'
});

server.auth.strategy('google', 'bell', {
    provider: 'google',
    password: 'private_key',
    clientId: 'client_id',
    clientSecret: 'client_secret',
    location: 'same_origin_registered_with_google'
});
```

And these are my two routes

```
server.route({
    method: ['GET', 'POST'],
    path: '/login/google',
    config: {
        auth: {
            strategy: 'google',
            mode: 'try'
        },
        plugins: { 'hapi-auth-cookie': { redirectTo: false } },
        handler: (request, reply) => {
            if (!request.auth.isAuthenticated) {
                return reply('Authentication failed due to: ' + request.auth.error.message);
            }

            let creds = request.auth.credentials;

            request.cookieAuth.set({
                token: creds.token,
                userId: creds.profile.id
            });

            return reply.redirect('/');
        }
    }
});

server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/',
    handler: (request, reply) => {
        return reply('hello');
    }
});
```

To note, the auth cookie is being set and once the redirect loop has exited I can navigate to the "/" route manually no problem.

Any help with this is much appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to `hapi-auth-cookie` not yet dealing with the `isSameSite` cookie option in hapi 15 causing the cookie to not being sent back to the server.

You can solve this by manually setting the option.

More information can be found in the hapi 15 release notes https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/issues/3323 and the PR on `hapi-auth-cookie` https://github.com/hapijs/hapi-auth-cookie/pull/142

Comment: Not sure why maintainer is not merging this PR.

Comment: @Subin The PR is now merged :D

Comment: Is there any security leak doing isSameSite Lax?

Answer (score 1):

This fixes problem:

```
server.auth.strategy('session', 'cookie', true, {
   password: 'private_key',
   redirectTo: '/login/google',
   isSameSite: 'Lax'
});
```